# Different results running same code from rascal-eclipse and rascal-shell

Tags: rascal

When I run the following code in Rascal I get different results.

```
module t01

import IO;
import lang::java::m3::AST;

public void main() {
  Declaration d;
  println("Hello.");
}
```

If I run it from Rascal Eclipse I get this result:

```
rascal>import t01;
ok

rascal>main();
Hello.
ok
```

But when I try to run on Rascal Shell I get this error:

```
Version: 0.7.2.201502061450
rascal>import t01;
ok
rascal>main();
|cwd:///t01.rsc|(75,11,<7,2>,<7,13>): Undeclared type: Declaration
[Advice](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/UndeclaredType/UndeclaredType.html)
```

If I comment the line `Declaration d;` both run without error and produce the same result.

Versions:

- Rascal Shell: 0.7.2.201502061450 (build by myself with the last commit 
  9a8a772158453a876622a6e537a2f60eaf76fad1)
- Rascal Eclipse: 0.7.2.201502061317

Comment: looks like a bug! can you submit it on github?

Comment: Yes, I can. Should I submit it on rascal issue track? Because rascal-shell doesn't have one.